# Unable to execute "sudo su -" in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I normally reach a machine via ssh with the following commands:

```
ssh myuser@192.168.10.1
```

Then as "myuser" I become user jboss as follows (No password requested):

```
$ sudo su - jboss
```

I need to replicate the same behavior with Ansible but the result is:

```
fatal: [192.168.10.1] => Missing become password
```

Here is my yml file:

```
- name: Hello Ansible - quick start
  hosts: webservers
  user: myuser
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: jboss

  tasks:
    - name: Hello server
      shell: /home/jboss/script.sh
```

As per documentation it seems correct, however it isn't. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the docs, this exact method is not possible.

> Only one method may be enabled per host
>
> Methods cannot be chained. You cannot use sudo /bin/su - to become a user,
>   you need to have privileges to run the command as that user in sudo or be
>   able to su directly to it (the same for pbrun, pfexec or other supported methods).
>   [source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#only-one-method-may-be-enabled-per-host)

Maybe "become_method: su" would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not able to validate it right now, though I will update the answer asap